# General Difference between a Filter and an Interceptor?

Tags: filter, aop, interceptor

There a several technologies offering filters and interceptors or both. But from my point of view it is pretty much the same.

Lets take for example Servlet filters: they wrap the execution of a request, they can modify the request or the response.

```java
public void doFilter(
    ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
  // do something BEFORE here ...      
  chain.doFilter(request, response);
  // do something AFTER here ...
}
```

An interceptor, for example one from the AOP Alliance, does essentially the same:

```java
class TracingInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
  Object invoke(MethodInvocation i) throws Throwable {
    // do something BEFORE here
    Object ret=i.proceed();
    // do something AFTER here
    return ret;
  }
}
```

The only difference here is due to technological details like method invocations vs. http requests.

Note that this are just examples, the question itself is technology agnostic.

**What is the difference? And if there is no real difference: what term should be preferred and why?**

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia suggests that filters are an implementation of the [interceptor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern):

> An example of implementation of this pattern is the javax.servlet.Filter interface, which is part of Java Platform, Enterprise Edition.